# Affine $k$-domain of dimension$1$ can always be embedded in a polynomial ring?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, field-theory, krull-dimension

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. Let $R$ be a UFD which is a finitely generated$k$-algebra.

If $\dim R=1$, then is it true that there exists an injective $k$-algebra homomorphism from $R$ to $k[X_1,...,X_n]$ for some $n$ ? Can we drop the condition $\dim R=1$ ?

(NOTE: For finitely generated$k$-algebra $R$, which is also an integral domain, $\dim R=tr.deg_k R$ )

Comment: Take $R=k[x,x^{-1}]$. In fact, units are the only obstruction with your hypothesis, and if you assume units are just constants, then $R=k[x]$. If $\dim R>1$, there are standard counterexamples.

Comment: @Mohan: thanks ... now I do remember seeing somewhere that if $k$ is algebraically closed of characteristic $0$ and $R$ is an affine $k$-domain which is also a UFD, of dimension $1$, then $R=k[X,\dfrac 1{P(X)}]$ for some $P(X) \in k[X]$.  Is thos still true in positive characteristic ?

Comment: It is true in all characteristics.

Comment: @Mohan: thanks, could you please kindly provide a reference ?

Comment: Search for Luroth's theorem.